# Python 3.6.1 While statement and asking for input

Tags: python-3.x

So I am new to python 3 and I just dont understand this. Ok, so I want to ask for an input then use a while loop. I want to keep asking the user until they enter the right integer.They can not pick an integer less than 0 or greater than 22. Here is what I have:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter number: ")
while (user<0) or (user>22):
    print ("try again, ", user_input)
    continue
```

So I just want to keep asking until they enter the right number. All I get back is nothing. Please can anyone explain this to me. I been researching this for hours and I cant get it.

Comment: Hint: After saying "try again", you need to allow the user to input something. So you need to ask the user for input once again

Comment: Im sorry, I where it says print ("try again, ", user). I meant to say print ("try again, ", user_input). Isnt that the same thing? Im asking the question again with user_input.

Comment: In your while loop you compare `user`, I believe you may want to compare `user_input`, unless it is a typo, or you will get an error for not defining the `user` variable.

Comment: It is a typo sorry @13smith_oliver. I still dont get what I want. Again just to keep asking the user for an correct input that is between 0 and 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from not understanding how `print` works

Check this out:

```
In [34]: user_input = int(input("Enter number: "))
Enter number: 15

In [35]: print("try again", user_input)
try again 15
```

It's like saying `print("try again", 5), which prints each argument (namely, the string`try again`and the int`5`), separated by a space. Take a look:

```
In [36]: print("try again", 5)
try again 5
```

You already know how to ask for user input (with that `input` function), so that's how you'd do it a second time:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter number: ")
while (user_input<0) or (user_input>22):
    print ("You entered", user_input)
    print ("That is invalid. Please try again")
    user_input = int(input("Enter number: ")
```

On another note, that `continue` is quite irrelevant here. You really don't need it